# deleting rows from datatable causes error

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am trying to remove rows that are not needed from a `DataTable`. Basically, there may be several rows where the `itemID` is identical. I want to find the rows where the column `"failEmail" = "fail"`, and using the `itemID` of those rows, remove all rows from the emails `DataTable` that have the same `itemID`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(emails.Rows.Count.ToString() + " emails!");

// create a list of the email IDs for records that will be deleted
List<DataRow> rows2Delete = new List<DataRow>();

foreach (DataRow dr in emails.Rows) 
{
   if (dr["failEmail"].ToString().ToLower() == "fail") 
   {
      rows2Delete.Add(dr);
   }
}

foreach (DataRow row in rows2Delete)
{
   DataRow[] drRowsToCheck =emails.Select("itemID ='" + row["itemID"].ToString()  +"'");
   foreach (DataRow drCheck in drRowsToCheck)
   {
      emails.Rows.RemovedDrCheck);
      emails.AcceptChanges();
   }
}
```

Here is the error message I am getting on the second pass:

> This row has been removed from a table and does not have any data. 
>   BeginEdit() will allow creation of new data in this row

How can I do what I need to without throwing errors like that? Is there a better way like using a `LiNQ` query?

Comment: Would simply calling the delete method work? Something like: `emails.rows[0].delete();`?

Comment: Also, if this is a copy/paste of your code, you have an errant bracket in this line: `emails.Rows.RemovedDrCheck);` either remove it or add the opening bracket so it says `emails.Rows.RemovedDrCheck();`

Comment: @armadadrive the issue is that only a couple of rows will initially have `fail`, I need to get the itemID of those ones, and then select all those...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what I ended up doing, based on an answer I got from MSDN c# Forums:

create an extension on DataTable to enable LINQ euering of the Datatable:

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<DataRow> RowsAsEnumerable ( this DataTable source )
        {
            return (source != null) ? source.Rows.OfType<DataRow>() : Enumerable.Empty<DataRow>();
        }
}
```

then modified my code as below:

```
//Get IDs to delete
var deleteIds = from r in emails.RowsAsEnumerable()
                 where String.Compare(r["failEmail"].ToString(), "fail", true) == 0
                 select r["itemID"];

//Get all rows to delete
var rows2Delete = (from r in emails.RowsAsEnumerable()
                  where deleteIds.Contains(r["itemID"])
                  select r).ToList();

//Now delete them
foreach (var row in rows2Delete)
    emails.Rows.Remove(row);
emails.AcceptChanges();
```

and now it works, just wish I could do it the normal way successfully.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when the same itemID has multiple entries with 'fail', you are trying to remove them multiple times.

```
// 1. Find the Unique itemIDs to remove
var idsToRemove = emails.Select("failEmail = 'fail'").Select (x => x["itemID"]).Distinct();
// 2. Find all the rows that match the itemIDs found
var rowsToRemove = emails.Select(string.Format("itemID in ({0})", string.Join(", ", idsToRemove)));
// 3. Remove the found rows.
foreach(var rowToRemove in rowsToRemove)
{
    emails.Rows.Remove(rowToRemove);
}
emails.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: I get an 'System.NullReferenceException' exception with your code - even though there are records in the datatable, and records that match the selection

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (DataRow rowFail in emails.Select("failEmail = 'fail'"))
        {
            DataRow[] rowsItem = emails.Select(String.Format("itemID = '{0}'", rowFail["itemID"]));

            for (int i = rowsItem.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                rowsItem[i].Delete();
            }
        }

        emails.AcceptChanges();
```

DataTable.Select returns an array of all DataRow objects that match the filter criteria.

Comment: Can you explain your answer

Comment: the issue is that only a couple of rows in the `emails`datatable will initially have `fail`, I need to get the itemID of those ones, and then select all rows mataching those itemIDs...